# Concatanate prefix to a jooq Uinteger type value

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I need to concatanate prefix to a UInteger type column value.Here I tried but the outcome is wrong as it concatanated as a suffix. Can anyone help me with this. note that PAYLK_TRANSACTIONS.ID is a UInteger type

```
Field<String> merchantRefID=PAYLK_TRANSACTIONS.ID.concat("p-");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`DSL.concat()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#concat-org.jooq.Field...-) using the "prefix" notation:

```
Field<String> merchantRefID = DSL.concat("p-", PAYLK_TRANSACTIONS.ID);
```

Or, you continue using the "infix" notation of [`Field.concat()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#concat-org.jooq.Field...-), but then you'll have to wrap your prefix in a `Field` explicitly:

```
Field<String> merchantRefID = DSL.val("p-").concat(PAYLK_TRANSACTIONS.ID);
```

Comment: Thanks. i followed the previous answers you have provided. but I couldn't find the "val" in the"impl.factory"
    import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

Comment: @RaveenJ: [`Factory` is a thing of a distant jOOQ past](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/reference/migrating-to-3.0/). What version are you currently using?

Comment: @RaveenJ: Interesting, but `DSL.val()` is right there in that version, isn't it? - Oh, I think I understand. You hadn't been *aware* of that method, right?

Comment: yes it was there. But earlier I referred your post (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jooq-user/qIJlk4JPZCc/7P02gapjLTQJ ) and there it has mentioned that .val() is in static org.jooq.impl.Factory.*

Comment: @RaveenJ: I see, thanks for the additional feedback. Yes - it is a bit unfortunate that those old posts to the user group can no longer be edited to update to the latest version...